# ReportNG Report with TestNG is not generated using WebDriver

Tags: eclipse, webdriver, automated-tests, testng, reportng

I am using Selenium WebDriver + TestNG with java in Eclipse. I want to generate better report using ReportNG rather than normal TestNG report. I have configured the build path with reportng-1.1.2.jar and velocity-dep-1.4.jar. I have also disabled the default TestNG Report from Project > Properties > TestNG > "Disable Default Listeners"
Presently I have created a testNg.xml file that runs my tests as complete Test Suite. The content of xml file is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" verbose="1" preserve-order="true" name="testingXML" junit="false" parallel="false" annotations="JDK">
<test verbose="2" name="com.src.com.pcrm.pageobjects.*" junit="false" annotations="JDK">
<testng classpathref="test-path"
            outputdir="${test-results.dir}"
            haltonfailure="true"
            useDefaultListeners="false"
           listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter">
      <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>
      <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="My Test Report"/>
    </testng>
<classes>
<class name="com.pcrm.pageobjects.HomeTest"/>
    <methods>   
        <include name="testManadatoryFieldsOnHomePage"/>
        <include name="testIsLogoDisplayed"/>
        <include name="testUrlCheck"/>
    </methods>
```

But When I executed this xml file it did not generate any ReportNG reports. What's the wrong? Help is appreciated.

Comment: "It doesn't generate any report" -- only this one line statement doesn't cover many things. What's the error displayed?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that it's a classpath issue.  Make certain that the ReportNG and Velocity JARs are on the classpath.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367643/reportng-does-not-provide-any-report) about a similar problem using ReportNG with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this [TestNG-XSLT](http://code.google.com/p/testng-xslt/) report, it look greater and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 : Download required Jar Files

from here :https://github.com/google/guice you can download below jar file

guice-3.0.jar

from here :http://reportng.uncommons.org/ you can download below jar files

```
reportng-1.1.4.jar
velocity-dep-1.4.jar
```

STEP 2 : Add Jar Files In Project's Build path

STEP 3 : Disable default listeners of testng

You need to disable default listeners of testng. 
To disable default listeners
Right click on project folder In eclipse.
Go to Properties. - It will open Properties dialog.
Go to TestNG and check Disable default listeners--->Apply--->Ok

STEP 4: add these listners in TestNG.xml

```
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
</listeners>
```

STEP 5 : Execute test and view ReportNG reports(inside html folder html-->index.html(not outside index.html))

refresh your project folder. It will create/update test-output folder. Explore that folder then explore html folder. You will find index.html file Inside It. To open index.html file.

Comment: I followed the same steps. ReportNG works but doesn't create `output` folder.